# Name of this tree?

Tags: identification, trees

[image]

Can someone identify this tree?  The top of the leaf is soft like velvet.

Comment: cmez29, welcome to Gardening SE! Please take a moment for the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site works. There is the [tag info for “identification”](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) and  [this post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872/for-id-questions-why-should-i-tell-where-in-the-world-a-plant-is-growing/) that help you write a good id question. Remember: you can always [edit] your own posts.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where you are, but if you're in USDA zone 9 or above, it is probably Conocarpus erectus var. sericeus, common name Silver Buttonwood. It has lots of small hairs coating the leaf surface, which is what gives the leaves a silvery appearance, and also makes them feel velvety to touch. Image and info here http://looking-at-plants.com/plants_a_-_z/conocarpus_erectus_var_sericeus

Comment: I'm in the UK so not sure what Fl means - I'm assuming Florida maybe? If so, the ID given is accurate...